# Image View Animations

Tags: android, imageview

I am working on sequential order of image animations. Here is my java activity file.

For each imageview i am using fadein, fadeout xml. But i could not able to get this animations one by one in a threading manner.

```
package com.cardio.android;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class guide extends Activity {

       //create name of animation
    Animation myFadeInAnimation;
    Animation myFadeOutAnimation;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     //grab the imageview and load the animations
        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ImageView myImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView myImageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView myImageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        ImageView myImageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
        Animation myFadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein1);
        Animation myFadeOutAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout1);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein2);
        Animation myFadeOutAnimation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout2);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein3);
        Animation myFadeOutAnimation3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout3);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein4);
        Animation myFadeOutAnimation4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout4);



    //fade it in, and fade it out. 
        myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
        myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation);
        myImageView1.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation1);
        myImageView1.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation1);
        myImageView2.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation2);
        myImageView2.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation2);
        myImageView3.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation3);
        myImageView3.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation3);
        myImageView4.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation4);
        myImageView4.startAnimation(myFadeOutAnimation4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ammmmm is there any Exception? Can we see your animation files?

Comment: fadein.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
    android:toAlpha="1.0" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"  
    android:duration="100000" android:repeatCount="infinite"/> 
</set>

Comment: fadeou.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"  
    android:duration="4000" android:repeatMode="reverse" android:repeatCount="infinite"/> 
</set>

This is my animation xml...kindly let me no any wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use onAnimationEnd event and in it trigger the next animation. You can create a loop to do it or just nest them into each other:

```
        myAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                   //here enter code for the next animation...

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                } 
            });
```